# Error in retrieving data from json using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to retrieve data from JSON and display it in html using JQUERY. After so many unsuccessful try's I am posting the code below

***HTML/Jquery***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>JSON</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="placeholder"></div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
  $.getJSON('file.json', function(data) {
        var output="<ul>";
        for (var i in data.reports) {
            output+="<li>" + data.reports.reportTitle[i] + " " + data.reports.reportDate[i] + "--" + data.reports.classificationType[i]+"</li>";
        }

        output+="</ul>";
        document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=output;
  });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

***Part of my Json***

```
{
    "errmsg": null,
    "reportType": "criteriaReport",
    "totalRecNumbers": 918,
    "navigationControl": {
        "dimensionGroups": [
            {
                "dimensions": [
                    {
                        "refinements": [],
                        "dimName": "dimGeography",
                        "dimId": 4294289122,
                        "appendedURI": "/api/v2/criteriaReport?N=363&Ne=4294289122"
                    },
                    {
                        "refinements": [],
                        "dimName": "dimMarketSector",
                        "dimId": 4294288493,
                        "appendedURI": "/api/v2/criteriaReport?N=363&Ne=4294288493"
                    },
                    {
                        "refinements": [],
                        "dimName": "dimSectorPageMarketSectors",
                        "dimId": 4294281954,
                        "appendedURI": "/api/v2/criteriaReport?N=363&Ne=4294281954"
                    }
                ],
                "dimGroupName": "Filter All Results",
                "dimGroupId": 2
            },
            {
                "dimensions": [
                    {
                        "refinements": [],
                        "dimName": "dimReportType",
                        "dimId": 11,
                        "appendedURI": "/api/v2/criteriaReport?N=363&Ne=11"
                    }
                ],
                "dimGroupName": "Filter Research Results",
                "dimGroupId": 3
            },
            {
                "dimensions": [
                    {
                        "refinements": [],
                        "dimName": "dimResearchLanguage",
                        "dimId": 1214,
                        "appendedURI": "/api/v2/criteriaReport?N=363&Ne=1214"
                    }
                ],
                "dimGroupName": "Filter by Language",
                "dimGroupId": 6
            },
            {
                "dimensions": [
                    {
                        "refinements": [],
                        "dimName": "dimDateRange",
                        "dimId": 14,
                        "appendedURI": "/api/v2/criteriaReport?N=363&Ne=14"
                    }
                ],
                "dimGroupName": "Filter Results by Date",
                "dimGroupId": 4
            },
            {
                "dimensions": [
                    {
                        "refinements": [],
                        "dimName": "dimMarketFocus",
                        "dimId": 1233,
                        "appendedURI": "/api/v2/criteriaReport?N=363&Ne=1233"
                    }
                ],
                "dimGroupName": "",
                "dimGroupId": 0
            }
        ],
        "breadCrumbs": [
            {
                "dimensions": [
                    {
                        "refinements": [
                            {
                                "refinementId": 11,
                                "refinementName": "dimReportType",
                                "dimensionID": 11,
                                "appendURI": "N/A"
                            },
                            {
                                "refinementId": 363,
                                "refinementName": "Rating Criteria",
                                "dimensionID": 11,
                                "appendURI": "/api/v2/criteriaReport?N=363"
                            }
                        ],
                        "dimName": "dimReportType",
                        "dimId": 11,
                        "appendedURI": "N/A"
                    }
                ],
                "dimGroupName": "N/A"
            }
        ]
    },
    "pagingInfo": {
        "totalPageNumber": 19,
        "nextSets": null,
        "previousSets": null,
        "pages": [
            {
                "pageNum": 1,
                "subSetRange": "1 - 50",
                "appendedURI": "/api/v2/criteriaReport?N=363&No=0"
            },
            {
                "pageNum": 2,
                "subSetRange": "51 - 100",
                "appendedURI": "/api/v2/criteriaReport?N=363&No=50"
            },
            {
                "pageNum": 3,
                "subSetRange": "101 - 150",
                "appendedURI": "/api/v2/criteriaReport?N=363&No=100"
            },
            {
                "pageNum": 4,
                "subSetRange": "151 - 200",
                "appendedURI": "/api/v2/criteriaReport?N=363&No=150"
            },
            {
                "pageNum": 5,
                "subSetRange": "201 - 250",
                "appendedURI": "/api/v2/criteriaReport?N=363&No=200"
            },
            {
                "pageNum": 6,
                "subSetRange": "251 - 300",
                "appendedURI": "/api/v2/criteriaReport?N=363&No=250"
            },
            {
                "pageNum": 7,
                "subSetRange": "301 - 350",
                "appendedURI": "/api/v2/criteriaReport?N=363&No=300"
            },
            {
                "pageNum": 8,
                "subSetRange": "351 - 400",
                "appendedURI": "/api/v2/criteriaReport?N=363&No=350"
            },
            {
                "pageNum": 9,
                "subSetRange": "401 - 450",
                "appendedURI": "/api/v2/criteriaReport?N=363&No=400"
            },
            {
                "pageNum": 10,
                "subSetRange": "451 - 500",
                "appendedURI": "/api/v2/criteriaReport?N=363&No=450"
            }
        ]
    },
    "reports": [
        {
            "reportTitle": "Criteria Addendum: Greece",
            "reportDate": "6/26/15 12:00 AM",
            "summary": "This report outlines Fitch Ratings assumptions for analysing securities backed by Greek residential mortgage loans.",
            "filePath": "/creditdesk/reports/report_frame.cfm?rpt_id=867293",
            "classificationType": "Sector Specific",
            "marketSectors": "Covered Bonds",
            "premium": true
        },
        {
            "reportTitle": "Global Credit Card ABS Rating Criteria",
            "reportDate": "6/26/15 12:00 AM",
            "summary": "This global criteria report describes Fitch Ratings methodology for analyzing securitizations of credit card receivables and may be applied to both international and national credit ratings. Global Credit Card ABS Rating Criteria is effective for new and existing ratings as of June 26, 2015.",
            "filePath": "/creditdesk/reports/report_frame.cfm?rpt_id=867482",
            "classificationType": "Sector Specific",
            "marketSectors": "Credit Cards - Prime, Credit Cards - Prime/Sub-Prime, Credit Cards - Retail, Credit Cards - Sub-Prime",
            "premium": true
        },
```

All I am trying is to retrieve the fields after "reports" in the json file.Thanks in advance

Comment: look at the browser console & network tab to see whether there are any error logged

Comment: i suggest you go to console and check the structur of data you received and than write code according to it for reading data

Comment: What fails? Do you get errors? Have you tried dumping the returned data from your ajax-call in the console to check if you get anything at all? It is hard to tell what is the problem with so little information.

Answer (score 1):

As `data.reports` is `array` you've to use subscript on `data.reports`.

Change

```
data.reports.reportTitle[i]
```

To

```
data.reports[i].reportTitle
//          ^^^  Should be here
```

Change the `for` as follow:

```
for (var i in data.reports) {
    output += "<li>" + data.reports[i].reportTitle + " " + data.reports[i].reportDate + "--" + data.reports[i].classificationType + "</li>";
}
```